# Change boot2docker memory assignment

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I've been playing around with docker on a mac so I need to install boot2docker to make it work.

I have a pretty powerful machine and a very resource hungry app so I want to up the available memory from the default which is [1GB](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md) to something like 8GB.

---

**This is what I've tried**

Booting boot2dock with the --memory param

```
boot2docker --memory=8116 boot
```

Change the config file

```
Verbose = true
VBM = "VBoxManage"
SSH = "ssh"
SSHGen = "ssh-keygen"
SSHKey = "/Users/mjsilva/.ssh/id_boot2docker"
VM = "boot2docker-vm"
Dir = "/Users/mjsilva/.boot2docker"
ISO = "/Users/mjsilva/.boot2docker/boot2docker.iso"
VMDK = ""
DiskSize = 20000
Memory = 8116
SSHPort = 2022
DockerPort = 2375
HostIP = "192.168.59.3"
DHCPIP = "192.168.59.99"
NetMask = [255, 255, 255, 0]
LowerIP = "192.168.59.103"
UpperIP = "192.168.59.254"
DHCPEnabled = true
Serial = false
SerialFile = "/Users/mjsilva/.boot2docker/boot2docker-vm.sock"
```

and then booting boot2docker

```
boot2docker boot
```

None of this approaches seem to work. I only end up only having the default memory.

---

The only way I manage to change was going to virtualbox GUI shutdown boot2docker, change it manually and boot it again.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You will need to re-initialize the boot2docker VM with the new memory settings:

```
$ boot2docker delete
$ boot2docker init -m 5555
... lots of output ...
$ boot2docker info
{ ... "Memory":5555 ...}
```

You can now `boot2docker up` and the image will always use the configured amount of memory.

Comment: When I try to run with the -m flag I get an `unknown shorthand flag: 'm' in -m` error.  Does anyone know why?  (boot2docker version returns `Client version: v1.2.0  Git commit: a551732`

Comment: I get the same issue as @cjhin

Comment: Can you try running `boot2docker version` and `boot2docker help`? The flag exists (at least) since 1.1.2 for Mac OSX

Comment: Mine also complains that -m is an invalid flag. Client version 1.2.0, Git hash: a551732

Comment: Ah, this is a bug that apparently have been fixed in the master branch (https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker-cli/pull/243). A work around is to manually change the Memory using the VirtualBox Admin GUI program.

Comment: See the answers below which mean you don't have to destroy your VM. I have up voted them and down voted this (sorry) so readers will go to the better answer.

Comment: WARNING: This will delete your downloaded images :(

Comment: No need to delete, look at the below answers, modify works.  Voting them up, please do the same, so ppl don't waste time.

Answer (score 42):

As `boot2docker init -m` did not work in my version of boot2docker, I just used VBoxManage command:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm boot2docker-vm --memory 3500
```

Also, using this I believe you can avoid destroying your VM, you should just `stop` it and then `start` again.

Comment: In recent versions of boot2docker, the vm name is `boot2docker-vm`

Comment: I realized after some time that boot2docker comes with fully capable VirtualBox UI. So you can just `boot2docker stop`, then type `VirtualBox` in your terminal, VirtualBox GUI will open where you can adjust parameters of you VM.

Answer (score 30):

It is NOT necessary to `delete` your `boot2docker vm` as Abel Muiño said.

Its enough what to do what Alex Petrenko proposed.

1. `boot2docker stop`
2. `VBoxManage modifyvm boot2docker-vm --memory 3500`
3. `boot2docker start`

Comment: This comment is same as Alex Petrenko's Oct 2014 answer.  For now voted them both up.  But folks may want to consolidate them into one.  For boot2doccer on windows I have used: `/c/Program\ Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe modifyvm boot2docker-vm --memory 6144`

Answer (score 3):

You can just tweak the settings in the GUI as well.

1. Open VirtualBox
2. Select 'boot2docker-vm'
3. Click settings
4. Select system
5. Tweak your RAM

No need to delete your boot2docker vm.

Comment: Not sure why I got down-voted.  It's a legitimate change that is an alternative to command line tinkering that may suite non dev/opts users  (content editors, analysts etc).

Answer (score 3):

When you are working on a Mac you do not necessarily need to use `boot2docker`. Usually I use [`docker-machine`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/). With that you can also easily create a VM matching your requirements like:

```
docker-machine create --virtualbox-disk-size "50000" --virtualbox-cpu-count "4" --virtualbox-memory "8116" -d virtualbox dev
```

That creates a VM called `dev` with a 50GB disk, using 4 CPUs and 8GB of memory.

You can list your created VM with `docker-machine ls` and get the IP address to connect with `docker-machine ip dev`.

Answer (score 1):

In case your using boot2docker in hyperv. Docker has driver specific cli arguments.

LIST : https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/

HyperV : https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/#options

eg to create:
`docker-machine create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Multiplexor" Boot2Docker --hyperv-memory "8192" --hyperv-cpu-count "4" --hyperv-disk-size "40000" --hyperv-static-macaddress "00:15:1D:01:F4:11"`